# Show/Hide buttons if i don't have access

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an api which identify if i have any permissions. What i want to do, is to show/hide a button if i don't have an specific permission.

This is the code where i'm consume the api:

```
function users (){
        $http.get('/api/users')
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.thisUser = data.data.Response;
            //console.log($scope.thisUser);
        });
    }
```

It response something like this:

```
0:{RoleName: "basic user", Select: true}
1:{RoleName: "advance user", Select: false}
```

How can i pass on an ng-show/ng-hide the params to allow or deny the visibility of the next button, if, per example, i don't have the `advance user` permission `(if Select: false)`:

```
<button class="btn btn-info">Next Step</button>
```

I don't trigger any search for the permission, because when i'm consuming the api, it identifies the permission of the user.

I'm using AngularJs and Javascript.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just do:

    <button ng-show="thisUser.Select" class="btn btn-info">Next Step</button>

Won't this work?

Comment: (Obligatory comment) Of course you must not rely on front-end code or element visibility to enforce auth on your system - remember to have the *server* check that people are allowed to do whatever they're trying to do, and don't just rely on hiding a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use find or some

```
isUserAdvanced() {
     return  $scope.thisUser.some(role => role.Select)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use the library called [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4), you should be able to do

```
<button ng-show="isUserAdvanced()" class="btn btn-info">Next Step</button>
```

And then add a new method as follows:

```
    isUserAdvanced() {
        return _.findIndexOf( $scope.thisUser, {RoleName: "advanced user", Select: true}) != -1;
  }
```

As @skyboyer mentioned, it is probably better do to this without the lodash dependency:

```
isUserAdvanced() {
            return $scope.thisUser.some(role => role.Select && role.RoleName == "advanced user");
      }
```

Comment: it's better to use native functions: `$scope.thisUser.some(role => role.Select)`

Comment: @skyboyer Do you mind if I add that to my answer with attribution of course?

Comment: not a problem, do on your own. 
meanwhile Sajeetharan already did it already :D

Comment: I just realized that may not work as is. See my updated answer. Does that make sense?

Comment: @holyfire I see what do you mean. if check should really operates  both role name and permission flag it's better for asker to refactor that anyway. Checking for role name has never been flexible enough.